# where is a good place to store non code files like mp3's for javascript testing with codepen?

Tags: javascript, url, cloud, mp3

I am in the processing of learning how to use the howler.js sound library, but I do not know where to upload my mp3s so that I can access them from code pen.  I have tried both dropbox and google drive, but both give me funny urls that do not have the mp3 in the file name.  When I try to play the files on my javascript codepen test location, it does not know how to interpret the url to successfully load the mp3 files.

Here are samples of the urls I get from google and dropbox
Google: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5QHq_oPha0yamJ0Z2U0UWVwNDA
Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5olrybllboufgen/LE0.mp3?dl=0

I saw this question [How to chain sounds on howler.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105483/how-to-chain-sounds-on-howler-js)

In the first answer, in the sample code there was a link

```
urls: ['http://shrt.tf/abcdefg.mp3']
```

and another

```
src="http://shrt.tf/howler.js"
```

Where can I put my mp3 files so that I can get a similar link that codepen can use to load my files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a similar question [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37698/where-is-a-good-place-to-store-online-music-which-can-be-accessible-by-html-and).

The answer given was to use git and GitHub.  And this is a very good solution for hosting .mp3 files for testing in web based or javascript project development.